# ValueError: Target 254 is out of upper bound

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I want to train a pretrained paddle model for segmentation on my data, you can find it here https://github.com/PaddlePaddle/PaddleSeg/blob/release/2.5/docs/whole_process.md .

But I always got an error . When I use the data that the model has been trained on everything works fine but when I use mine I got an error . So I'm 100% sure that the problem is my data .

So I tried to readjust my data and make it adapted to what the model needs but I still got an error .
What I want is to display all the properties of the 2 images ( 1 image from my data and the other one from the model's data ) and see where the diff exists

```
    from PIL import Image
     
    image = Image.open('/content/PaddleSeg/data/abdomen/labels/0048d8dcaee83ad4538885a73d97ff616455f8737f21384779bafcb14f061f53.png')
    
    print("Filename: ", image.filename)
    print("Format: ", image.format)
    print("Mode: ", image.mode)
    print("Size: ", image.size)
    print("Width: ", image.width)
    print("Height: ", image.height)
    print("Is Animated: ", (getattr(image, "is_animated", False)))
    print("Frames in Image", getattr(image, "n_frames", 1))
    image.close()   # close image file
```

When I run the code above to compare the model's data and mine , I found that my data got RGB mode instead of P , so I convert it . But I still got the same problem

Before changing the mode to P I used to have this error when I launch the training script :

```
ValueError: Target 254 is out of upper bound.
```

But after changing it I got this error when I launch the training script:

```
ValueError: Target 225 is out of upper bound.
```

So the target value decreases , I'm doubting that they are others propreties that are not the same . so I want to displaay all possible proprites and make them equals to each other .

This is my original image and its mask :

[image: original]

[image: masks]

This is the original images and its mask that the model has been trained on :

[image: pretrained_image]

[image: pretrained_mask]

Comment: please present a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

I found out that my mask images had the wrong max values.

Every pixel should be either 0 or 1.

Your data has a max value of 254 and 225 which is too much.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @klirfa , I did in fact normalize all the pixels so their values will be always between 0 and 1 but all the images went blaack , I had no answer till now about that but thank you mate